# Reflection on IDictionary doesn't reveal anything about KeyValuePair

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I use reflection on interfaces to determine exactly which methods in an implementing type are from the interface (vs overloads which are not from the interface).  This works very well for System assemblies, except for one case: `System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

From MSDN I know that `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, but I can't find anywhere via reflection where you can find "KeyValuePair" stated.  Currently, I'm using some specific logic for IDictionary to work around this problem, but I'd like to be able to treat IDictionary as I do the other interfaces and not have to code directly to this idiosyncrasy.

Here's a code snippet (remember, it virtually always works, except for the generic IDictionary):

```
foreach (System.Type asmType in SystemAssembly.GetExportedTypes())
{
    if (asmType.IsInterface)
    {
        //is there anything in the System.Type object which will tell me that the interface implements ICollection<KeyValuePair<...>> ?

        //at this point, I call 'GetMethods', and for IDictionary methods where I expect a KeyValuePair parameter, I get a System.Object parameter instead
        foreach (MethodInfo method in asmType.GetMethods(...binding flags...))
        {
            ParameterInfo[] parameters = method.GetParameters();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Resolution: Lee's answer nailed it - it finally got to where I could see "KeyValuePair" via reflection.

Comment: Please show the code you're using... and note that `IDictionary` and `IDictionary<,>` are very different types.

Comment: You are looking at the non-generic version of `IDictionary`

Comment: @leppie: (thanks for the edit). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea(v=vs.110).aspx.  The question is how to determine this only via reflection.

Comment: @leppie: No, see the link I gave.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov:  I've edited the question to be clear that it's the generic IDictionary.

Comment: Please post the code you're using.

Comment: You are looking for something like `Type.BaseType` and than [Type.GenericTypeArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.generictypearguments%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)... but I'm not sure how you want to use them.

Comment: @JonSkeet: There's not much code to show - once I have the System.Type instance for this generic IDictionary interface, I see nothing in its properties (including its sub-interfaces) which suggests that KeyValuePair is involved in any way.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I've looked through these properties - do you see anything there which mentions KeyValuePair for the generic IDictionary?

Comment: Or maybe you are looking for [Type.GetInterfaceMap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfacemap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: "Not much" isn't the same as "none". You're claiming that you've poked around with reflection and not seen what you expect - which suggests you should be able to provide a short but complete program which you would expect to show one thing, but it actually shows something else.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I've added a partial code snippet - if you can see either at the type level or the method level, where "KeyValuePair" appears *anywhere*, that would be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why are you using GetExportedTypes? That seems an odd method to use here.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I'm not interested in the types that aren't visible outside the assembly.  This is for use in a source code converter - source code will not reference types that are only visible within the assembly.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: Fair enough - in fact that probably isn't a relevant difference, but it looked like it while I was reading the code on the sofa on a mobile :) I suspect `GetMethods` isn't returning explicit interface implementations, which may be the important point. Perhaps you should look at the implemented interfaces instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a type instance for the open `IDictionary<,>` type you can do something like:

```
Type dictType = typeof(IDictionary<,>);
var icolIface = dictType.GetInterfaces()
                .First(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>));

Type colType = icolIface.GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

Comment: When I'm gathering the reflection information, I don't know the specific types that are used for the IDictionary generic types (e.g., I don't know "string, string").

Comment: @DaveDoknjas - It still works the same if `dictType` is `typeof(IDictionary<,>)`, `colType` will be `KeyValuePair<,>`.

Answer (score 1):

This small snippets shows the method calls and properties to use to get the `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` type out of the dictionary.

```
var someDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

var kvType = someDictionary.GetType().GetInterfaces()
  .Single(i => i.Name == "ICollection`1")
  .GetGenericArguments().Single();
```

Because I don't know exactly what you are after, I hard coded the selection of the `` ICollection`1 `` interface out of the interfaces implemented.

Comment: I want to find that "KeyValuePair" is involved without hard coding the specific types, such as "int, string".

Comment: +1. @DaveDoknjas Use `typeof(IDictionary<,>).GetInterfaces()`... Since you have not shown your code it is very hard to reason what inputs you have.

Comment: Updated the code, to make it more clear on how to start with a variable.